# Getting pdfsizeopt working

Tags: python, pdf

I am having some difficulty getting pdfsizeopt working on an AWS Ubuntu instance.

I have followed the directions at https://code.google.com/p/pdfsizeopt/wiki/InstallationInstructionLinux except replacing v1 with v2 of the tar file since v1 doesn't exist.

The file it creates is pdfsizeopt.py and not pdfsizeopt.  After making it executable and running ./pdfsizeopt.py --use-pngout=no lme_v6.pdf, I get "AssertionError Ghostscript gs does not seem to work." An earlier message says "sh: gs: not found".

Comment: Have you installed ghostscript? And this is better suited to http://unix.stackexchange.com/ or http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: The installation instructions say that the tar file includes all dependencies. I'm not sure why those would be better places to ask.

Comment: Ubuntu has interesting packaging techniques, so the people over at askubuntu.com might know better what's going on.

Comment: Resolved this by moving the files from pdfsizeopt_libexec to pdfsizeopt.try.

Comment: Please don't use comments to answer questions, even if it's your own question.